# DC analysis of P-type MOSFET circuit

Tags: mosfet, analysis

For the following circuit I am trying to calculate the DC drain current \$I_{DQ}\$
[image: circuit P type MOSFET]

I know firstly that while doing a DC analysis the capacitors act as open circuits. This means that there will be zero current flowing into the gate.

Doing KVL around the gate / source loop:

\$-3 + 1200I_D + V_{SG} =0 \$

\$ \implies V_{SG} = 3 -1200I_D\$

This is also a P type MOSFET so the drain current is given by the expression:

\$I_{DQ} = k_p(V_{SG}+V_{TP})^2\$

and substituting \$V_{SG}\$ into the equation above gives

\$I_{DQ} = k_p(3 - 1200I_{DQ}+V_{TP})^2\$

Given \$K_p = 800\mu \frac{A}{V^2}\$ and \$V_{TP}=-0.4V\$, I solve for \$ I_{DQ}=4.03mA\$

However the answer is given as \$1.16mA\$.

I know that this is quite basic but I feel that the error is a fundamental error rather than a calculation one. Could someone please explain to me which of my assumptions were not correct?

Comment: MOSFETs don't have a base terminal.

Comment: You forgot about the square $$I_D = K(V_{GS} - V_T)^2$$

Comment: Look here https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x+%3D+0.8%28%283+-+1.2x%29+-+0.4%29%5E2

Comment: We have two solution but only one has physical meaning do you see which one it is and why?

Comment: @G36 Thank you for your answer. What is the physical meaning of the two values for ID? How would I know to pick the one root of the equation and not the other?

Comment: @G36 I think the answer of 4mA doesn't have any physical meaning because the maximum current which may flow is determined by the supply rails and RD and RS? I calculate that the maximum current which may flow is 2.8mA?

Comment: Yep. or you could apply the KVL to both of your answers and see what you get. 3V - Id*Rs = 0

Comment: @G36 Thanks for your help!

Comment: I'm glad I could help.